# Is it a good approach to call a method on a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've noticed that I've been doing this a lot (mostly because all my methods are non-static):

```
var person = new Person();
var addresses = person.GetAddresses();
```

A lot of times I just need to call the method once inside my other method. I noticed I can just do this instead:

```
var addresses = new Person().GetAddresses();
```

Is there any problems doing it that way? It seems like a lot less typing for me. For example, if I wanted to load a model with addresses, I can just do:

```
public ActionResult HelloWorld() {
    var model = new MyModel { Addresses = new Person().GetAddresses() };
    return View(model);
}
```

What do you guys think?

Btw, my methods are non-static because I'm using a repository. My class is setup something like this:

```
private IMyRepository _myRepository = new MyRepository();

Person () {
    // initialize properties
}

// Constructor for unit testing...
Person (IMyRepository repository) : this() {
   _myRepository = repository;
}

public GetAddresses() {
    return _myRepository.GetAddresses();
}
```

Comment: The person class is a repository and your POCO/Model? If so it's Active Record, not Repository pattern! If not, shouldn't it be named PersonRepository?
If you want to retrieve Addresses how about an AddressRepository class with a GetAddressesByPerson method?

Comment: I just updated my question with more code on how my Person class is set up. It is using a repository. It's not a repository itself.

Comment: Why Person constructor receives a IMyRepository? Your model classes must be decoupled from data access and never bother about it. Seems like you are violating [Single Responsability Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I think the "IPersonRepository" implementation must be responsible for SETTING the Addressess attribute (or something like that) of your model.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the "model" portion of my question. Basically I have the model (or ViewModel) as a separate class. Person isn't the model. Person is more part of my business logic. I have Person receive IMyRepository so that I can unit test it against a test repository that doesn't hit the database. Otherwise, how would I unit test the Person class? I could add another dependency injection layer, but I think that's overkill...

Comment: Either way is good, but what's better is that you are returning a model in the view.  This is know as strong-type binding and is a good pattern in MVC.

Comment: When I say Model I mean Business Logic, and that to me is where to problem is laying. Your business logic code must not be dependent on your data access code. I may be missing something, but I can't see the architecture you're trying to achieve here, try to give more insight on this.

Comment: I guess your `Person` is some sort of a service that could receive other repositories where all **related** things can happen. If that's the case and you really need to call the method in one place then it's fine. But it's always better (if not best) to put an instance a variable. In that way if that method needs to be called again then you don't need a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to do that, it won't cause any problems. Though it is questionable to have a class that's immediately thrown away. Maybe `GetAddresses` should be static?

But in any case, it's perfectly fine to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's non-static because I'm using a repository pattern. That way I can easily unit test the class easily.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok to do that,
but if you want to some jobs just after creating an object of person,
you can create an event and raise it in your constructor , then you have your object and some custom data in your own event args in your main class.
if it is helpful I can send you a sample code